# Xcode 11.2.1 Bug: Storyboard not editable

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode-storyboard, xcode11

I am experiencing a weird issue in my Xcode Storyboard. After opening my project some `ViewControllers` turned into a non-usable state. Everything is blacked out and I see only borders of my `UIElements`.

Is anyone else also experiencing this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weirdly only restarting the Mac and Xcode worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is XCode issue.

Press the top right corner button "Code review" (ref screen) button twice Storyboard reload correctly.

[image]

Comment: Sadly this didn't solve the issues with Interface Builder.